# Can I use any Collection with the <f:table collection="${AnyCollectionList}

Tags: grails, grails-3.1

List myObjectList = new ArrayList()

Can I use any Collection with the

```
<f:table collection="${myObjectList}"/>
```

I am trying it and getting nothing.

Comment: [Docs](http://grails3-plugins.github.io/fields/snapshot/ref/Tags/table.html) say that you don't need to use `${}`. Haven't used `ftable` myself though.

Comment: Please show us an example.